# Is the address of an class instance equal with the address of the unique element in the class

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

I am investigating a piece of code in C+ that has been compiled with g++-7.4 
My question is if it is safe to return  the address of a class member from class B, and assigned this  as pointer of class A , in which this member is unique.
Let 's do it clear with the following example

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
class DummyMsg
{
public:
    DummyMsg () = default;
    DummyMsg(const DummyMsg &) = default;
    ~DummyMsg()=default;
};
class ROCallContext
{
public:
    ROCallContext() = default;
    ROCallContext(const ROCallContext &) = default;
    ~ROCallContext() = default;
    DummyMsg *dummyMsg;
};
class RWCallContext
{
public:
    RWCallContext()
    {
        dummyMsg = new DummyMsg();
    }
    ~RWCallContext()
    {
    }
    void* getDummyMsg()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<void *>(dummyMsg);
    }
    int i;
    double d;
    char * pc;
    DummyMsg *dummyMsg;
    char c_array[100];

};
int main()
{
    RWCallContext * rwCallContext = new RWCallContext();

    ROCallContext * ctx = reinterpret_cast<ROCallContext *>(rwCallContext->getDummyMsg());

}
```

Is the ROCallContext::dummyMsg equal with the RWCallContext::dummyMsg? 
Are the content of the ROCallContext::dummyMsg equal with the RWCallContext::dummyMsg the same?

Is it depend on the compiler optimizations?

Comment: I think the definition of "minimal" for the "minimal working example" was lost.  Other things you should look up: rule of 3/5

Comment: @UKMonkey I disagree. This is pretty good

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? Maybe I'm missing something with what you're trying to do, but it seems you're basically doing `(ROCallContext*) ((void*)new DummyMsg())` and expecting to have a usable `ROCallContext`.

Comment: @Justin compared to some - sure.  Compared to what is actually minimal to demonstrate the problem, it's at least double what it needs to be; and in its attempt to be more complex, there's at least one call for UB

Comment: No , I do not expect that this work. But I am not sure.  However this work under 4.8 compiler but seems that this does not work with 7.4

Comment: @UKMonkey If you already know the problem, sure, you can minimize this further. If you don't, this is perfectly fine.You don't need to have the most-minimal example to be a minimal working example. Especially if it's something like this where you don't get an error message, just undefined behavior

Comment: If you had a `new ROCallContext` instead of `new DummyMsg`, this would be valid.

Comment: @Justin, there was a typo in the code .Both of the RoCallContext and RWCallContext have the same DummyMsg instance

Comment: @scohe001, there was a typo in the code. Both of the RoCallContext and RWCallContext have the same DummyMsg instance

Comment: @getsoubl Is that supposed to be `reinterpret_cast<void*>(&dummyMsg)`?

Comment: It is supposed to be reinterpret_cast<void*>(dummyMsg)

Comment: What are you trying to do by `reinterpret_cast`ing unrelated non-trivial types?

Comment: @Zereges,  my question is if this works in the case that the ROCallContext class has DummyMsg as unique member

Comment: This sounds like a backwards version of the permission to `reinterpret_cast` between a class object and its first member.  You can’t do it when there is no outer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is gonna be a real hit or miss since your question is a bit fuzzy.

Is it safe to pass the pointer around.. yeah, sure, if you keep track of it, which you probably wont be able to when the code gets larger. If you need to pass pointers around, please use shared_ptr instead.

Anyway, if you run this code it will hopefully explain your second question if the pointers are equal. Hope it makes sense to you.

```
#include <iostream>
class DummyMsg {
    public:
        int i = 0;
};

class ROCallContext {
    public:
        ROCallContext(DummyMsg *msg) {
            dummyMsg = msg;
        }
        DummyMsg *dummyMsg;
};

class RWCallContext {
    public:
        RWCallContext() {
            dummyMsg = new DummyMsg();
        }
        DummyMsg* getDummyMsg() { 
            return dummyMsg;
        }
        DummyMsg *dummyMsg;
};
int main() {
    RWCallContext * rwCallContext = new RWCallContext();
    ROCallContext * ctx = new ROCallContext(rwCallContext->getDummyMsg());
    printf("Address of RW is %p\n", (void *)rwCallContext->dummyMsg);
    printf("Address of RO is %p\n", (void *)ctx->dummyMsg);
    printf("RO i: %i\n", ctx->dummyMsg->i);
    printf("RW i: %i\n", rwCallContext->dummyMsg->i);
    printf("Changing value for RW\n");
    rwCallContext->dummyMsg->i = 2;
    printf("RO i: %i\n", ctx->dummyMsg->i);
    printf("RW i: %i\n", rwCallContext->dummyMsg->i);
    delete rwCallContext->dummyMsg;
    delete rwCallContext;
    delete ctx;
}
```

Edit: Just realized that the question might be if dummyMsg will be the same value even if the class you cast from/into do not have the same structure.
If that is the case, maybe this example explains why it probably will not have the same values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct B {
    int y;
    int x;
};

int main() {
    struct A a = {1, 2};
    struct B *b = (struct B*)&a;
    printf("Struct A x: %i, y: %i\n", a.x, a.y);
    printf("Struct B x: %i, y: %i\n", b->x, b->y);
}

Output:
Struct A x: 1, y: 2
Struct B x: 2, y: 1
```